# Manually balancing Li-ion battery pack

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-chemistry, cell-balancing

[image: pack configuration]

I have a battery pack which is currently 13 series and 3 paralell.

Cells are Lithuim Ion.

I want to make it into 16 series and 4 paralell.

As far as i know it's a very good idea to make the old cells and the new cells a similar state of charge before i add them to the groups

( red = current pack, blue = cells i want to add in parallel)

The green cells are all new so should be all the same state of charge already.

The groups in the old pack are unbalanced.

What is the best way to discharge the red cells to match the blue? the Red are mostly around 4.1v and the blue about 3.8v.

Could i just connect a load (such as a halogen bulb) to each red paralell group in turn until the voltages go to about 3.8? or is voltage not a good indicator of state of charge?

Comment: It's actually a very good idea not to mix old and new cells.

Comment: The old cells only have about 20 or so charge cycles on them, and they are the same type, the issue is the old bms went haywire and decided to completly discharge 3 paralell  banks so i don't want to lose the whole pack just because of that. Is there a way to do it better?

Comment: What about adding just the green cells in series, as each bank is monitored by the bms would that lead to any issues?